# My c++ project works in vc++ 2008 but not in vc++ 2010

Tags: c++, dll

I have two vc++ dll projects, which will generate two dlls. A

```
vector<vector<string>>
```

object will pass from one dll to another dll. Both of the projects are configured as multithreaded debug dll. And both can be compiled succesfully on vc++ 2008 AND vc++ 2010. However, only the dlls generated from vc++ 2008 projects work. The dlls will be used by another dll compiled under MSDEV version 6.0. So my question is why the

```
vector<vector<string>>
```

object cannot be passed between the dlls builted by vc++ 2010? Thx:)

Comment: In most cases dll's produced in vc++ 2008 and 2010 are not compatible. Ran into this at work the other day. I don't remember the exception but my vs2010 code would crash the moment it tried to call into the vs2008 dll.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can not use STL types in DLL interfaces, if you plan to use different compiler versions for the DLL and the code that uses it.

The implementations of vector and string may differ (and they seem to do in your case), and you will get problems like this.

Comment: I'm surprised that the VC++ 2008-compiled DLLs worked with DLLs compiled by VC6.

Answer (score 0):

VC++ 2010 uses the new C++11 standard which involves big changes to template containers like vector (using rvalue references and move semantics, for a start).

If you're sharing libraries like that, generally the safest option is to make plain, boring standard C interface functions to everything. Those work pretty much everywhere, after all. The internal implementation can then be done in which ever way you see fit.