# Can OpenCV libraries be called from a C++/CX app?

Tags: opencv, c++-cx

Is it technically possible (I don't *think* this would be restricted), and how do you go about it?

I got my little test app building fine, but when I run it I get a failure dialog.

[image: WinRT app fails]

The debug output is slightly more informative:

```
The thread 0xe4c has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135).
The program '[3400] OpenCVTest2.exe' has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135) 'A dependent dll was not found'.
```

Then I created a Win8 Desktop app, which also built fine but failed to run.

[image: Win8 Desktop app fails]

MSVP100D.dll is part of the [VC++ 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14632) which is not compatible with Win8.  (Being a hacker I tried it anyway, the installer runs to completion - but the bits aren't installed.)

Is there a compiler flag I can try?  Possibly a custom build of OpenCV would fix it, but that would be a last resort, and it might only fix the desktop app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This guy shows an example of using OpenCV library for performing face detection in a Windows 8 Store app written using C++/CX:
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2012/DEV322

Also, at the below post he also describes how the C++ Runtime works for Windows 8Store apps:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/09/28/10354327.aspx

Answer (score 1):

MSVP100D is not a part of VC10 redist. Note the "D" at the end of its name. That package only includes release builds. Your release builds should work fine. But mixing libraries from different VC versions might get you in trouble. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11028595/400303). Your best chance is to build from source with VC11.

Comment: Doing a release build fixed the desktop app, thanks.  The release build did *not* fix the WinRT app, I still get the same (uninformative) error message.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://blog.nuclex-games.com/2012/03/how-to-consume-dlls-in-a-winrt-metro-project/)